# Magento 2.3 want to trace collection object

Tags: magento2.3, collection

I am getting NULL in where condition of product collection query on category page. I want to trace where from NULL getting added.

how can I trace collection query. I have tried debug_backtrace() as well but not helpful.

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = '1'
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE ((NULL) AND (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1)) AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) LIMIT 9
```

any help would be appreciated.